# C struct values garbled

Tags: c, pipe

Having the problem with the sender and receiver of the `checksum`. where I am using the struct to define the variables to be written into the pipe.

```
struct ANSWER
{
    int arr[BUFFER];
    int counter;
    int ans;
}a;
```

The mechanism used for `checksum` is :

```
int chck(int value[],int count)
{
    int i,sum=0,checksum;
    for ( i=0; i<count; i++)
    {
        sum+=value[i];
    }
    printf("SUM IS :%d \n",sum);
    checksum=checksum^sum;
    printf("CHECKSUM IS : %d",checksum);
    return checksum;
}
```

The main problem is in writing in the pipe as

```
write(pipe,a,sizeof(a));
```

This writes all the contains using struct.

While at receiver side having problem in retrieving the specific values 
when I retrieve the values at receiver side I get garbled values in `count` and `ans` variables.

```
read(pipe,a,sizeof(a));
printf("COUNT : \n ",a.counter);
```

the values turn out to be garbled.

Main area:

```
void main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    int pipe,i;

    pipe = open("devil",O_WRONLY);

    if ( pipe == -1 )
    {
        printf("ERROR NO PIPE FOUND \n");
    }

    printf("ENTER NUMBER OF ELEMENT : ");
    scanf("%d",a.counter);

    for ( i=0; i<a.counter; i++)
    {
        printf("ENTER NUMBER :");
        scanf("%d",&a.arr[i]);
    }

    a.ans=chck(a.arr,a.counter);

    printf("CHECKSUM IS : %d \n",a.ans);

    write(pipe,&a,sizeof(a));

}
```

Comment: Please create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), one that shows you actually using and initializing the structure. And how do the checksum function come into this?

Comment: printf has no format string

Comment: You are not calling `write` and `read` correctly. Turn on all compiler warnings and try again.

Comment: Should be writing from &a (i.e. the argument should be address of a -- not a).

Comment: Also checksum variable not initialized.

Comment: @RaymondChen thanks for suggestion. but i have performed it correctly in my whole code this was just for an overview. The main problem for me is am unable to fetch proper values of the array which i have specified. There is some problem in read operation.

Comment: @GilHamilton  I have edited the code with my main. please suggest any option. to this.
Thanks

Comment: Check return values of functions (read/write/scanf etc).

Comment: @hyde If you are talking about check function it's return type is int and hence am returning the **int cheksum.** But for instance suppose, I'm making the function void and not returning anything. still the problem continues in reading the pipe

Comment: You still haven't initialized checksum before you use it in `checksum=checksum^sum;` so the result of the xor will be indeterminate. Second, you should also be passing &a as the buffer address to read. Otherwise, you are passing the entire structure as an argument rather than the address of the structure. (I suspect you have disabled compiler warnings [a bad idea] or you would have already seen that.)

Comment: No, I mean, when ever you use functions like open, read, write, *scanf (output to stdout/stderr is the only exception, usually), check their return value. Doubly so when you have code which does not work right.

Comment: @hyde Thanks man for suggestion got it by solving some unix issues and some pipe functions. Your suggestion was helpful thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turning comment to answer, I suggest you add error checking to all your system and standard library calls (except printing to stdout/stderr, that's more clutter than it's worth for almost any app), something like:

```
int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    int pipe, i;

    pipe = open("devil",O_WRONLY);
    if ( pipe == -1 )
    {
        perror("open pipe");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    printf("ENTER NUMBER OF ELEMENT : ");
    if (scanf("%d",&a.counter) != 1) 
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "scanf count IO or parse error, or EOF\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    for ( i=0; i<a.counter; i++)
    {
        printf("ENTER NUMBER :");
        if (scanf("%d",&a.arr[i]) != 1)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "scanf number IO or parse error, or EOF\n");
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }
    }

    a.ans=chck(a.arr,a.counter);
    printf("CHECKSUM IS : %d \n",a.ans);
    i = write(pipe,&a,sizeof(a));
    if (i == -1)
    {
        perror("write to pipe");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    else if (i != sizeof(a))
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "write to pipe, partial write!\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Notes: For pedantic code, `write` actually returns type `ssize_t`. I changed return type of `main` to `int` as that is required by standard. Please read manual page / docs of `perror` to understand what it does and how it prints the actual error message. `EXIT_FAILURE` and `EXIT_SUCCESS` are constants for the two standard-defined return values or exit codes, usually 1 and 0 respectively. And in a larger program, you would probably write helper functions or macros for error handling, and split the entire main function into multiple functions, to make the code look less cluttered.

---

Additionally, you use `checksum` variable uninitialized in `chck` function. You should probably initialize it to 0, something like:

```
int chck(int value[],int count)
{
    int i = 0, sum = 0, checksum = 0;
    ....
```

In general, you should avoid having uninitialzied variables, it's too easy to forget when first using them, like demonstrated here... Also, turn on compiler warnings, so you will *usually* get a warning if you still do that accidentally.

---

One more bug: your first scanf was missing `&` to get pointer to `a.counter` (required for `scanf`, to actually modify the original variable). A good compiler may also be smart enough to warn about passing suspicious arguments to `scanf`.

Comment: Thanks man for the suggestion I made some basic changes and that worked out for me, But I tried your way also it was also helpful. Thanks again for suggestions appreciated.